# Power Series of a sin of a power series

Tags: analysis, power-series, approximation, formal-power-series

I was wondering if there exists a power series for the sin of a power series, in other words: which is the formula for the coefficients $\xi_{\lambda}$ in terms of the $f_{\lambda}$ in the expansion:

$\sin \left(\sum_{\lambda=0}^{\infty} f_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\lambda} \right) = \sum_{\lambda=0}^{\infty} \xi_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\lambda}$

assuming that $\sin(f_{0})=0$? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Euler wouldn't have asked he would just substitute one series into the other and expand, then collect like term. You may not be the greatest mathematician of all time like Euler but I would encourage you to be just as adventurous.

Comment: $\xi_n$ is given by [Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula):
$$[\epsilon^n] \sin \left( \pi l + \sum_{k \geq 1} f_k \epsilon^k \right) = \\
\frac {(-1)^l} {n!} \sum_{1 \leq k \leq \left \lfloor \frac {n + 1} 2 \right \rfloor}
 (-1)^{k - 1} B_{n, 2 k - 1}
 (1! \hspace {1.5px} f_1, 2! \hspace {1.5px} f_2, \ldots,
  (n - 2 k + 2)! \hspace {1.5px} f_{n - 2 k + 2}).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Maxim! I really appreciated your time and effort! Not that convenient formula but is the correct answer

Comment: @CyclotomicField ”...in most cases where we seek in vain the answer to a question, the cause of the failure lies in the fact that problems simpler and easier than the one in hand have been either not at all or incompletely solved. All depends, then, on finding out these easier problems, and on solving them by means of devices as perfect as possible and of concepts capable of generalization.” (David Hilbert)

Answer (score 0):

There is a series, but it’s not so easy to calculate the coefficients. The most natural thing is to write $F(x)=\sum_{\lambda=1}^\infty f_\lambda x^\lambda$, and then use the series expansion of $\bigl(F(x)\bigr)^n$ for as many odd values of $n$ as you need. Note that if you tell yourself that you’re willing to settle for, say, the first $7$ terms of the resulting series, you can throw away all monomials with exponents $>7$, and thus have no more work than to calculate the first, third, fifth, and seventh powers of $F$.

There are fancier ways of doing this, and you can read about “Formal power series” in Wikipedia, where about half-way through the topic of composition of power series is broached.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lubin! I really appreciated your time and effort! I got what you mean! Thanks also for the reference!

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be simpler if summing to $n$ instead of $\infty$.  $$\sin \left(\sum_{\lambda=0}^{n} f_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\lambda} \right) = \sum_{\lambda=0}^{n} \xi_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\lambda}$$ In such a case (this is the tricky part), we could consider that
$$\sum_{\lambda=0}^{n} f_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\lambda}=\sum_{\lambda=0}^{n} f_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\lambda}+O(\epsilon^{n+1})$$ and
$$\sum_{\lambda=0}^{n} \xi_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\lambda}=\sum_{\lambda=0}^{n} \xi_{\lambda}\epsilon^{\lambda}+O(\epsilon^{n+1})$$

and compose Taylor series.

For a try, use $n=4$. Without any restriction, this would give
$$\sin (f_0)+f_1 \epsilon  \cos (f_0)+\epsilon ^2 \left(f_2 \cos
   (f_0)-\frac{1}{2} f_1^2 \sin (f_0)\right)+\epsilon ^3 \left(-f_2 f_1 \sin
   (f_0)-\frac{1}{6} f_1^3 \cos (f_0)+f_3 \cos (f_0)\right)+\epsilon ^4
   \left(\frac{1}{24} f_1^4 \sin (f_0)-\frac{1}{2} \left(f_2^2+2 f_1
   f_3\right) \sin (f_0)-\frac{1}{2} f_2 f_1^2 \cos (f_0)+f_4 \cos
   (f_0)\right)+O\left(\epsilon ^5\right)$$ For sure, if $\sin(f_0)=0$ this would simplify a lot to
$$f_1 \epsilon  \cos (f_0)+f_2 \epsilon ^2 \cos (f_0)-\frac{1}{6} \epsilon ^3
   \left(\left(f_1^3-6 f_3\right) \cos (f_0)\right)-\frac{1}{2} \epsilon ^4
   \left(\left(f_1^2 f_2-2 f_4\right) \cos (f_0)\right)+O\left(\epsilon
   ^5\right)$$ which could again simplify since $\cos(f_0)=\pm 1$. So, we should have
$$\pm\left(f_1 \epsilon  +f_2 \epsilon ^2 -\frac{1}{6} 
   \left(f_1^3-6 f_3\right)\epsilon ^3 -\frac{1}{2} 
   \left(f_1^2 f_2-2 f_4\right)\epsilon ^4 +O\left(\epsilon
   ^5\right) \right)$$

I think that the generalization could be difficult (not to say improssible if we make $n\to  \infty$).

Comment: Thanks a lot Claude! I really appreciated your time and effort!